# How to calculate roll up summary using dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

Hi I have a dataset like this, the date difference between each sprint is 14 days.

```
 Team       DateBegin   Sprint   Points
   Team1      1/2/2021    Sprint1   30
   Team1      1/16/2021   Sprint2   40
   Team1      1/30/2021   Sprint3   20
   Team1      2/13/2021   Sprint4   70
   Team1      2/27/2021   Sprint5   90
   Team1      3/11/2021   Sprint6   55
   Team1      3/25/2021   Sprint7   40
   Team2      1/2/2021    Sprint1   30
   Team2      1/16/2021   Sprint2   40
   Team2      1/30/2021   Sprint3   20
   Team2      2/13/2021   Sprint4   70
   Team2      2/27/2021   Sprint5   90
   Team2      3/11/2021   Sprint6   55
   Team2      3/25/2021   Sprint7   40
```

I wanted to calculate the Sum average using the last 3 sprints.
for example

```
for Sprint7- sum(Sprint6+Sprint5+Sprint4)/3
For Sprint6- sum(Sprint5+Sprint4+Sprint3)/3
```

Something like For each Sprint look up the last 3 sprints and Sum them up and take the average(measure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can average the points for the 3 prior sprints like this:

```
Last3Avg =
VAR ThisSprintStart = SELECTEDVALUE ( Sprints[DateBegin] )
VAR SprintsToDate =
    FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( Sprints ), Sprints[DateBegin] < ThisSprintStart )
RETURN
    AVERAGEX ( TOPN ( 3, SprintsToDate, Sprints[DateBegin] ), [Points] )
```

Comment: Thanks Alexis, the formula does what intended to do but I forgot to mention that I have another column which I wanted to use it as a Group by which is the "Team" column I have added now. Can you help

Comment: Which means I want to calculate the average within each team and sprints included within that team..whenever I am jumping to another team, the calculation should start all over again.

Comment: Try ALLEXCEPT(Sprints, Sprints[Team]) instead of ALLSELECTED(Sprints).

Comment: Using ALLEXCEPT did not bring the right result. the ALLSelected works fine for the calculation. Only thing is adding Group by Team?

Comment: Hi Alexis, any help on the above question? I apologize for asking simple questions, it is just I am new to powerbi and dax. thank you!!

Comment: Ah, right. What I suggested doesn't work inside the FILTER. Try specifying the team as part of the filter condition instead by adding `&& Sprints[Team] = MAX ( Sprints[Team] )` directly after `Sprints[DateBegin] < ThisSprintStart`.

Comment: Thank you!! that works. I appreciate the help.